# How to add meta tags in wordpress archive page?

Tags: wordpress, seo, meta-tags, metatag, meta-title

I am using wordpress site, I couldn't edit archive page for adding meta tags. How should I add meta tags to archive page?

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the [YOAST SEO plugin](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/), this is great for all round SEO but also allows you to specify meta tags for archives.

Answer (score 0):

you can set "if" for archive in header page
"[is archive](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive)" is good resource

Answer (score -1):

[Siegfried](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1791472/siegfried-grimbeek) is right, anyway you can always modify the archive.php template in the theme and do some hardcoded modifications.